# How to solve "cannot set using a multi-index selection indexer with a different length than the value"

Tags: python, dataframe

I am working on add a new column to a dataframe and then I am going to assign a list to each cell of this new column.

```
x['Leaking pipe']=0
x['Leaking pipe']=x['Leaking pipe'].astype('object')
x.at[:,'Leaking pipe']=['p31','p158','p183','p232','p257','p369','p427','p461','p538','p628','p654','p673',
              'p810','p866']
x
```

After running the code shown above, it returned an error :`cannot set using a multi-index selection indexer with a different length than the value`.

So how can I fix this problem.
Would appreciate a lot if any advices!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Tt8P.png)

Comment: `x=['Leaking pipe']=0` is not valid

Comment: Could you please show the content of x? It seems that fixing the mistake pointed by @Epsi95 your code runs. But the error that you mentioned it is not associated with the mistake on your first line.

Comment: @Epsi95 sorry, that's a typo. It should be x['Leaking pipe']=0.

Comment: @Romero_91 I have posted the content of x, please check them and Could you please give me some ideas to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code is not working is because you have a multi-index DataFrame. To assign a list in each cell in this case you should do something like this (if you have only 2 index class):

```
for i,j in x.index: x.at[(i,j),'Leaking pipe'] = ['p31','p158','p183']
```

Is not that elegant, but it worked for me.